# Advanced MySQL IF function

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am trying to do an IF function in MySQL that i thought would be pretty straightforward, but seems to be a little for complex.

Here's the idea:

`SELECT IF(score1>score2, (name1,score1,name2,score2),(name2,score2,name1,score1)) 
AS (winner,w_score,loser,l_score)
FROM game table`

what I am trying to do is test score1 > score2, depending on the result, order the fields I want.

Comment: I'm not sure you can reorder the fields in your select using `IF`. You should probably do that outside of the query, like in PHP (or whatever language you're using).

Comment: the first three below all work great. Thanks.

Comment: You can use nested IF statements like this: https://janac.medium.com/if-statements-in-mysql-conditional-logic-7e5acab4e8a8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you need is four different IF statements:

```
SELECT 
    IF(score1 > score2, name1, name2) AS winner,
    IF(score1 > score2, score1, score2) AS w_score,
    IF(score1 > score2, name2, name1) AS loser,
    IF(score1 > score2, score2, score1) AS l_score
FROM game_table
```

It's not the prettiest thing, but as the comparison is pretty straightforward, it should behave fine.

Answer (score 1):

Considering if `score1` ,`score2` ,`name1` ,`name2` are the column names in your `game` table , you could do like this :

```
SELECT
     IF( score1 > score2 ,name1 ,name2 ) AS winner
    ,GREATEST( score1 ,score2 ) AS w_score
    ,IF( score1 > score2 ,name2 ,name1 ) AS loser
    ,LEAST( score1 ,score2 ) AS l_score
FROM
    game
```

Comment: Neat. Never seen the `GREATEST` and `LEAST` functions before :)

Answer (score 0):

I offer a simple solution:

```
SELECT name1 AS winner, score1 AS w_score, name2 AS looser, score2 AS l_score
FROM game table WHERE score1 > score2
UNION
SELECT name2 AS winner, score2 AS w_score, name1 AS looser, score1 AS l_score
FROM game table WHERE score2 > score1
```